# How do I return two observables joined as the same observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm having trouble getting a function to return. It has a condition that would return an Observable, and another condition that I would like to return the results of two observables with the results of successful being merged together.

Something like this.

```
getSearchFeed(): Observable<items[]> {
   if (this.condition) {
     return this.populateItemsArray();            //function Returns Items Array Observable
   } 

   //second condition
   const someItems = this.populateSearch();       //function Returns Items Array Observable
   const otherItems = this.populateOtherSearch(); //function Returns Items Array Observable

   return forkJoin(someItems,otherItems)
    .pipe((res:Array) => {
      return [...res[0],...res[1]];
   });
}
```

Other posts talk about joining the results, which I understand how to subscribe and join. My question is more on the lines of how can I return an Observerable for the second condition.

Some of the other things I've tried,

```
return forkJoin(someItems,otherItems)
 .pipe(map((res:Array<Observerable<Items[]>>) => {
    return [...res[0],res[1]];
});
```

and

```
const source = of([someItems,otherItems]);
const merged = source.pipe(mergeMap( q => forkJoin(...q)));
return merged;
```

Comment: I understand it's your right to downvote the question, but could you please explain why so I have more grounds to improve my question?

Comment: hey there, did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe you might be right but it isn't the right syntax. I'm looking into toArray

Comment: I feel like it should work, but it still has a return type of Observable<Items[], Items[]>

Answer (score 1):

For this situation, you can use the `toArray()` RxJS operator. According to the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/toarray.html), the `toArray()` operator

> Collects all source emissions and emits them as an array when the source completes.

This is how your code should look like. Doing so will concatenate the returned observables into a single array.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

getSearchFeed(): Observable<items[]> {
   if (this.condition) {
     return this.populateItemsArray();            //function Returns Items Array Observable
   } 

   //second condition
   const someItems = this.populateSearch();       //function Returns Items Array Observable
   const otherItems = this.populateOtherSearch(); //function Returns Items Array Observable

   return forkJoin(someItems,otherItems)
     .pipe(
       toArray(),
     );
}
```

---

Edit: I just noticed the return type, and that I should be flattening the returned observables into a single array. In that case, you can simply use [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) within the map operator, and that should flatten it into a single array.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getSearchFeed(): Observable<items[]> {
   if (this.condition) {
     return this.populateItemsArray();            //function Returns Items Array Observable
   } 

   //second condition
   const someItems = this.populateSearch();       //function Returns Items Array Observable
   const otherItems = this.populateOtherSearch(); //function Returns Items Array Observable

   return forkJoin(someItems,otherItems)
     .pipe(
       map(res => res.flat(2))
     );
}
```

Comment: I think this is close but it is still off. To me this makes sense but when I try it the exact message I get when trying this is
Type 'Observable<(Items| [Items[], Items[]])[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Items[]>'.

Comment: @ModestMonk hi! I just noticed the return type. In that case, my answer might be a bit off. Let me edit it..

Comment: I tried the second edit. It looks like that fails to flatten because it currently is an array of observables, not an array of items.